# Logging with Email and Password , Not with Username Yii 2

Tags: email, authentication, yii2

How I can manage to login with email address,not with the standart (username + password).I enter the website with my Users in my DataBase , but is there a way to change that to be with email address instead of that user name , because when I use Gii , I got a lot of errors , even I try to fix those errors

Comment: http://codingbin.com/yii-login-with-email-only/ read this answer here

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, try to locate your SiteController or any other Controller you use for the index route. It should have an action function that corresponds to the login route; it is usually with signature  `public function actionLogin()`.

You should see the initialized model (usually, the LoginForm model). The model should have a function for login logic which is checked to determine user authenticity. You should find that this function invokes another `login` function which requires the User object as first argument/parameter. The function is usually the `$this->getUser()` function.

Looking into this will point to you a call to the actual data model that fetches user by whatever criteria/property you specify; this can be email or anything else that might not even need be unique but generally, you want to use a unique data property like `username` and `email`. This function relies on the User data model. It, by Gii default, calls the function `User::findByUsername(search_property)`

Yii2 provides a default User model that implements the Identity interface; that's where you want to make the adjustment you need. It should have the required static function `findByUsername()` or something similar. You would find that Yii2 default searches within static data to find user, you should link that to you (User) data model which I assume you generated using Gii.

My Gii sequence usually looks like such:

1. List item
2. Generate the yii2-basic/yii2-advanced using composer
3. Create Database (I have a user table in there) and set proper db credentials in `config/db.php`
4. Rename the default `model/User.php` to `model/OldUser.php`
5. Create Data Models using Gii
6. Make the newly generated User Model implement IdentityInterface to allow Yii2 freely-given session management by adding `implements yii\web\IdentityInterface` to the class declaration.
7. Implement all the required methods of the IdentityInterface. You can check in `model/OldUser.php' for guidance.
8. Create static functions to `findUserByEmail($email)` or `findUserByUsername($username)`

Mine usually look like [this](https://gist.github.com/Funso-Popoola/4491d2f094b7e67a9925bc1f45e82c01)

I hope this helps.

Comment: Very nicely explained. (Y) +1

Comment: @Funso Poola really thanks for the answer ,I will try it now

Comment: @FunsoPopoola I have some problems with that login , because I have only id,email,password,First name,Last name in my table , I try to fix it but got some errors any idea , I did it in ur way,and my users that are link to the database are Loginusers,not new User folder

Comment: http://pastebin.com/QNNfHANv
http://pastebin.com/aQht95VL
Unknown Property – yii\base\UnknownPropertyException
Getting unknown property: app\models\LoginForm::email

Answer (score 0):

I made it just change everywhere where must be email,instead of username,because of Yii default username loggin , thank u for the advices